# Strings and int comparsion for yahoo weather API

Tags: android, string, int, arrays, yahoo-weather-api

I'm developing a simple weather applications using the yahoo API.

The method `weatherInfo.getCurrentText()` results in a string with the current weather condition in English.

For each weather condition there is an assigned code ([list of condition + code here](https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/805520))

What I would like to do is to get the code with `weatherInfo.getCurrentCode()` and use a custom string. This will allow me to provide correct translations.

I'm trying to do this with string-array:

```
<string-array name="weather_conditions">
    <item0>Sunny</item0>
    <item1>Cloudy</item1>
     etc...
</string-array>
```

So, once I get the weather code is there any way I can assign the item on my string array?

mWeatherCode = get the code (assuming 10)

mText.setText(the item10 on my array list)

Comment: thanks @Chilledrat for edit and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] conditions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weather_conditions);
if(mWeatherCode < 0 || mWeatherCode > conditions.length) {
    mText.setText(R.string.err_invalid_condition);
} else {
    mText.setText(conditions[mWeatherCode]);
}
```

Comment: should i keep useing <item1> <item2> etc on my array list or can i just use <item> <item> <item> etc... thanks for the solution meanwhile!

Comment: @iGui90 Just use `<item>...</item>`. The Yahoo API starts counting at 0 and the ADK does so, too. Well, you'll need to handle 3200 specifically.